why I got error when run new page oracle apex : page not found?
I have running application using oracle apex and I want to add more new pages the issue from 2 days
I can create new pages but when I run the page I got error
 oracle apex page not found 

what happen why I got this error and how to solve this issue in application
and is this general issue in oracle apex ?
I created another new application and there is no issue and I can run the page , but in this running application I cannot run new pages only old pages was working without any error
what is the reason and solution please ?
Thank you


You're going to need to add more details, particularly your project setup and the like.   How are you adding your new page.   What does the image even say?   Perhaps copy and paste that traceback and post it here.   A non-English image with a truncated traceback is useless.

If you're also a DBA of that database (or you can contact one), try to connect as SYS and then alter system flush shared_pool;. Return back to your Apex application and run the page. Any improvement?

@ewokx the project multi language Arabic and English I put default language Arabic , and I added the new page from create page button , the error show in Arabic language maybe because I put default Arabic language I will change it to English and see

Does page 29 in app 289 exist ? If it does and it still throws a page not found then the most probable cause is that there is a build option on the page with status "Exclude".
Components with a build option of status "Exclude" are excluded from the application at runtime. As a result, a page with such a build option will throw a page not found errors.
The "Build Option" attribute can be found in page attributes > configuration. In more recent versions of APEX, the component that has a build option with status "Exclude" shows with a strike through as shown in the picture below.

Build options can be managed in Shared Components > Application Logic > Build Options. Since APEX 23.2, there is a default build option called "Commented Out".


I checked build option for the page its not selected Commented out its empty

Yeah I see your answer - that information was not in the question but it makes sense :)

I think the issue related to Multi Language setup , I put the default language Arabic language in Login page process , I changed it to take language from the selected language like this
begin
apex_util.set_session_lang(:P9999_LANGUAGE);
--apex_util.set_session_lang(p_lang => 'ar-ae');
end;

After that I did seed and publish then the new pages running without errors
for multi language application when you do any updates on application like create new page it will appear in English language application version only but to appear in other added language like Arabic or French language you need to publish the application like the following steps :
1- Shared Components --> Globalizations --> Application Translation --> Seed transferable text --> select other language added application then click seed


2- when seed finish select again the application language then click on Publish

Thank you all
